# C error: Identifier <funtion_from_other_header> is undefined

Tags: c, undefined, identifier

I have absolutely no clue why I'm getting these errors. My code is something like this:

**type.h**

```
typedef struct {
  int* myInt;
} myType;
```

**class.h**

```
#ifndef myClass
#define myClass

#include "type.h"

void makeMyType( myType& t );
void deleteMyType ( myType& t );

#endif
```

**class.C**

```
#include "type.h"

makeMyType( myType& t ) { 
  t.myInt = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int));
  t.myInt = 0;
}
deleteMyType ( myType& t ) {
  free (t);
}
```

**useType.C**

```
#include "type.h"
#include "class.h"

int main {
  myType t;
  makeMyType (t);
  deleteMyType (t);
  return 0;
}
```

Then the compiler gives me the following:

```
error: identifier "makeMyType" is undefined
error: identifier "deleteMyType" is undefined
```

What could be causing this error? How can I fix it?

Comment: `class.c` doesn't seem to include `class.h`, why do you expect it to know about identifiers defined in `class.h`?

Comment: The errors are coming from useType.C, not class.C. And #including class.h in class.C doesn't seem to be helping

Comment: C doesn't have references. C++ has. Decide which language you want to use. You must specify return types of functions, and you must `#include <stdlib.h>` to use `malloc` and `free`. The errors you are getting [don't look very much like real errors from a real compiler](http://codingground.tutorialspoint.com:41957/index.htm?SESSIONID=irinom879kq7ke7s20coogl774).

Answer (score 0):

```
void makeMyType( myType& t );
void deleteMyType ( myType& t );
```

These 2 function prototypes are declared in `class.h` and not in `type.h` and you are including `type.h` in your `class.c` file which is why you are seeing this issue. `class.h` should be included in `class.c`

Answer (score 0):

In `class.c` include `class.h` instead of `type.h` and in `useType.c` include just `class.h`

type.h

```
typedef struct {
  int* myInt;
} myType;
```

class.h

```
#ifndef myClass
#define myClass

#include "type.h"

void makeMyType( myType& t );
void deleteMyType ( myType& t );

#endif
```

class.C

```
#include "class.h"

makeMyType( myType& t ) { 
  t.myInt = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int));
  t.myInt = 0;
}
deleteMyType ( myType& t ) {
  free (t);
}
```

useType.C

```
#include "class.h"

int main {
  myType t;
  makeMyType (t);
  deleteMyType (t);
  return 0;
}
```